# Sort orders by paid date in WooCommerce admin order list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I'm trying to sort store orders by date of payment, but there's a problem.

```php
function sp_41964737_custom_product_order( $query ){
    global $typenow;

    if( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $typenow == 'shop_order' ){
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_date_paid' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'sp_41964737_custom_product_order' );
```

After applying this code, nothing appears in my list of orders except the orders that have paid successfully, so actually only posts that have the `_date_paid` meta data.

Any advice to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your current code only shows orders for which the metakey actually exists.

To get around this, you can use:

```php
function action_parse_query( $query ) { 
    global $pagenow;

    // Initialize
    $query_vars = &$query->query_vars;
    
    // Only on WooCommerce admin order list
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $query_vars['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
        // Your meta key
        $meta_key = '_date_paid';
        
        // Define an additional meta query 
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'relation'    => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => $meta_key,
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => $meta_key,
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            )
        );
        
        // Set
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'action_parse_query', 10, 1 );
```

---

**Proof of concept:** the orders for which this meta exists will be displayed first.

[image]