# Change default sorting in Woocommerce order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can the default sorting of the Woocommerce order list be changed. For now each time I enter the order page, orders are displayed as DESC. I would like it to be ASC by default each time I enter the order page. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found another custom order solution in the forum:

[sort-orders-by-paid-date-in-woocommerce-admin-order-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496720/sort-orders-by-paid-date-in-woocommerce-admin-order-list)

I edited the code mentioned in there to the following, which worked out:

```
    function action_parse_query( $query ) { 
    global $pagenow;

    // Initialize
    $query_vars = &$query->query_vars;
    
    // Only on WooCommerce admin order list
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $query_vars['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {

        
        // Set
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'action_parse_query', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_orderby_shop_orders( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'shop_order' ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_orderby_shop_orders' );
```

Answer (score -1):

These code will do the work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_query_args', function ( $args ) {
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    
    return $args;
} );
```

Comment: I really appreciate your solution, unfortunately it did not do the job for me. I added it to the functions.php

Comment: Are you asking about the admin order page?